# Swiper JS, How to stop the swiper wrapper on touch in freemode?

Tags: swiper.js

I have a slider using swiper js in freemode that may have up to 100 slides, when the user swipes we need them to be able to stop the slider on touch or click.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes, I used the below function.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I used this function

```
function stopCarouselOnTouch() {
    var slider_wrap = $('.slider-wrap');
    var translation = getTransform(slider_wrap);


    var translationX = translation[0];
    var translationY = translation[1];
    var absX = Math.abs(translationX);
    var absY = Math.abs(translationY);

    // stops the carousel at the current value
    $('.swiper-wrapper').css({'transform': 'translate3d(' + translationX + 'px , ' + translationY + 'px, 0px)'});
    $('.swiper-wrapper').css('webkit-transition-duration', '0s');

    // finds css translation values
    function getTransform(el) {

        var transform = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('slider-wrap'), null).getPropertyValue('transform');
        var results = transform.match(/matrix(?:(3d)\(-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*(?:, -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)), -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*\)|\(-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*(?:, -{0,1}\d+\.?\d*)*(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))(?:, (-{0,1}\d+\.?\d*))\))/);

        var result = [0,0,0];
        if(results){
          if(results[1] == '3d'){
            result = results.slice(2,5);
          } else {
            results.push(0);
            result = results.slice(5, 9); // returns the [X,Y,Z,1] value;
          }

        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

And then I called it inside

```
on: {
 touchStart: function() {

  stopCarouselOnTouch();

 },
}
```